# Class equal with if on one property

Tags: c#, class, equals

I have a class that I use to describe a `XYZ` coordinate along with 3 properties.

The class looks like this:

```
class dwePoint
{
        public double X { get; set; }
        public double Y { get; set; }
        public double Z { get; set; }
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        public string Prop3 { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return Equals(obj as dwePoint);
        }

        protected bool Equals(dwePoint other)
        { //This doesnt seem to work
            if(Prop1== "Keep")
            {
                return false;
            }
            return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y) && Z.Equals(other.Z);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                var hashCode = X.GetHashCode();
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Y.GetHashCode();
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Prop1.GetHashCode();
                hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Z.GetHashCode();
                return hashCode;
            }
        }
}
```

Checking the `XYZ` on the `Equals`, I can filter out duplicates only based on the actual coordinates, ignoring the properties.
In my code, I use a list, so I call the `List.Distinct()`

Now there is one thing I cant figure out yet:
It is possible there are 2 points with the same `XYZ`, but with different properties.
In that case I always want to keep the one with a specific string (for example "Keep") and always remove the one that has some other value.

I was already trying some `if` statements, without any luck...

How should I handle this ?

Comment: *I was already trying some if statements*. Can you show?

Comment: @S.Akbari Edited my post; My logic was there is could be 2 points (or more) with the same XYZ where only 1 of the 2 has the "Keep" in Prop1; thus that one would be false, but checking the others should return it as a duplicate.

Comment: If you compare an object with `Prop1 == "Keep" with itself, this yields `false`, which is clearly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not really possible with `Distinct` since it uses your `Equals` as it's only input for equality (as it should), so it has no way to even be aware that there could be a difference between the objects.

I think it would be a better design for you to compose your class using a new class, e.g. `Point3D` containing your coordinates and your 3 properties. Then you can group by the point, and for everything that has more than one equal point, apply your own logic as to which to keep.

In code:

```
class Point3D
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }
    // Equals and get hash code here
}

class dwePoint
{
    Point3D Coordinate {get;}
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}

// Filter list by applying grouping and your custom logic
points = points.GroupBy(p => p.Coordinate)
    .Select(x => 
        x.OrderByDescending(p => p.Prop1 == "Keep")  // Sort so the element you want to keep is first
         .First()                                    // If there is only one element, the ordering will not matter
    ).ToList();
```

If you really want, the `GroupBy` also works with your current class design, since only the coordinates takes part in the `Equals`.

Comment: thank you for your explenation and code sample. Have to read it a few times to fully understand, but it helps me a lot (i have no professional coding background)

Comment: I got it to work and pretty much onderstand it now.
only 1 more thing i wonder. Can i specify my custom preffered order of strings ? so first pick would be "Keep" second "SomeName" third "SomethingElse" and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Your GetHashCode runs into a nullref if Prop1 == null, you should fix that.

And another solution: use Aggregate and Lamda to distinct your list. The Equal() on your class only compares the X,Y and Z - the Aggregate lambda makes sure you keep what you want. Probably put the Aggregate in a extension method or Function.

```
static void Main()
{
    List<dwePoint> points = new List<dwePoint>();
    // Testdata
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
            {
                points.Add(new dwePoint { X = x, Y = y, Z = z });
                if (x == y && x == z) // and some duplicates to Keep
                    points.Add(new dwePoint { X = x, Y = y, Z = z, Prop1 = "Keep" });
            }

    // prefer the ones with "Keep" in Prop1  
    var distincts = points.Aggregate(new HashSet<dwePoint>(), (acc, p) =>
    {
        if (acc.Contains(p))
        {
            var oldP = acc.First(point => point.X == p.X && point.Y == p.Y && point.Z == p.Z);
            if (oldP.Prop1 == "Keep")
            {
                // do nothing - error, second point with "keep"
            }
            else
            {
                acc.Remove(oldP);
                acc.Add(p); // to use this ones other props later on ....
            }
        }
        else
            acc.Add(p);

        return acc;
    }).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", points));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" - ", distincts));
    Console.ReadLine();
}


private class dwePoint
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as dwePoint);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = X.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Y.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ Z.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{X}-{Y}-{Z}-{Prop1}-{Prop2}-{Prop3}";

    protected bool Equals(dwePoint other)
    {
        return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y) && Z.Equals(other.Z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same answer in mind as driis provided..
But, I would like to provide you with another option.

You can write a Distinct on your own as an extension method.
Here is a work around. I wrote a sample code, so that you can understand better.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Abc> list = new List<Abc>()
        {
            new Abc()
            {
                a = 5,
                b = 6,
                s = "Phew"
            },
            new Abc()
            {
                a = 9,
                b = 10,
                s = "Phew"
            },
            new Abc()
            {
                a = 5,
                b = 6,
                s = "Keep"
            },
            new Abc()
            {
                a = 9,
                b = 10,
                s = "Keep"
            },
            new Abc()
            {
                a = 5,
                b = 6,
                s = "Phew"
            },
            new Abc()
            {
                a = 9,
                b = 10,
                s = "Phew"
            },
        };
        list = list.MyDistinct();
    }

    // Extension Method
    public static List<Abc> MyDistinct(this List<Abc> list)
    {
        List<Abc> newList = new List<Abc>();
        foreach (Abc item in list)
        {
            Abc found = newList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(item));
            if (found == null)
            {
                newList.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
                if (found.s != "Keep" && item.s == "Keep")
                {
                    newList.Remove(found);
                    newList.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }
}

class Abc
{
    public int a, b;
    public string s;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Abc other = obj as Abc;
        return a == other.a && b == other.b;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return a.GetHashCode() ^ b.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you..